# How to compare element of List passed as parameters?

Tags: prolog

How to compare two elements of two Lists in Prolog?
`find` should return next available route so `Departure` should be less or equal to `Dep`

```
%fact    
    plane('JFK','BLL', [13,00],[23,00]).
%rule
    find(A,B,Departure,Arrival):-
       plane(A,B,Dep,Arr)
       % compare Departure and Dep ...   to be sure we pick up right plane
```

Comment: @DanielLyons perhaps you meant `Departure @=< Dep`.

Comment: To make it a little easier, if time times are all within the current day, covert them to "minutes past midnight" first (e.g., `MpM is HH*60 + MM`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%fact    
    plane('JFK','BLL', [13,00],[23,00]).

%rule
    find_flight(A,B,Departure,Arrival):-
       plane(A,B,Dep,Arr),
       % compare Departure and Dep ...   to be sure we pick up right plane
       is_no_later_than(Departure, Dep).

    is_no_later_than([H1,M1], [H2,M2]) :-
       Mins1 is H1*60 + M1,
       Mins2 is H2*60 + M2,
       Mins1 =< Mins2.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the time is a list of two elements, you can use unification in the head to break the list into component parts:

```
% isNoEarlierThan( Time1, Time2 )
% is true just in case Time1 is equal to or later than Time2
isNoEarlierThan( [Time1Hours, Time1Mins], [Time2Hours, Time2Mins] ) :-
    Time1Hours >= Time2Hours,
    Time1Mins >= Time2Mins.
```

Then:

```
find(A,B,Departure,Arrival):-
   plane(A,B,Dep,Arr),
   isNoEarlierThan( Dep, Departure ),
   isNoEarlierThan( Arrival, Arr ).
```

Personally, I would use a `time/2` term instead of encoding the time as a length-2 list, because I think it expresses the intent more clearly and makes for more maintainable code.

Comment: looks like `isNoEarlierThan( [15,12], [14,14] )` will fail. Probably needs some tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple facts of the form `plane(Source,Dest,Dep,Arr)`, I would follow a previous comment about using binary terms instead of lists with 2 elements to represent times of departure/arrival. Also, from your description I assume that Departure is bound (i.e., given, so that you want to find a flight leaving before your "threshold"). Then. you can do something like this:

```
find(A,B,Departure,Arrival) :-
   plane(A,B,Dep,Arrival),
   is_earlier(Departure,Dep).

 is_earlier(time(Hr1,Min1),time(Hr2,Min2)) :-
   (Hr1 > Hr2
   -> fail
   ; (Hr1 == Hr2
      -> Min1 =< Min2
       ; fail)
    ).
```

Comment: Explicit fails in `is_earlier/2` are unnecessary. You can simply say `Hr1 < Hr2 ; (Hr1 = Hr2, Min1 =< Min2)`. Might be more clear with two clauses, one for hours that match, one for hours that are earlier.

Comment: That's not the same, your version leaves a choice point, but the one by Spyros does not. A declarative solution for such problems that also lets you  use the predicate in all directions (also if none of the arguments are known) are finite domain constraints, where you can post deterministic disjunctions with `(#\/)/2`.

Comment: How do You pass `List` as one of the parameters of `is_earlier` method and handle it / receive by `is_earlier` as a compound term? Shouldn't it be like `is_earlier([H1|T1],[H2|T2])` ?